# Block-scope for local variable

Tags: vb.net, scope

Is there a better way to create an arbitrary block in VB.Net to limit the scope of a local variable?  If have tried "If 1 Then", but it just looks kludgy.

```
If 1 Then
    Dim table = InputParameter1
    Dim new_row = table.AddRow
    new_row.field(1) = InputParameter3.user_value
End If
```

I just don't want to have `table` and `new_row` accessible later in the procedure.

Comment: Use a more meaningful name, this has the fringe benefit of improving your codes readability. If this is the best name in both places its a sign that you should have two functions. Can you provide a good and complete example where this is not the case?

Comment: I feel using a short name within a distinct section of the procedure is better for repeated field setting / method calling.  I'm just asking about other options to influence the .Net scoping of this short  name _without_ creating a new function just for this.  I like the scoping of 'this_entry' in `For Each this_entry In table.rows`, but I don't always need a `For` loop.

Comment: can you provide an example of a `Function` or `Sub`?

Comment: As a side note, I'd suggest the use of underscores in names is unusual in .Net langauges, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608443/underscore-or-camelcase

Comment: This isn't an object oriented question.  I just wanted a way to help me refactor the procedural code I inherited without moving the code around yet.  Creating in-procedure code blocks keeps the text comparable with the original version and doesn't change the execution chain.  I will introduce classes in place of these repetitious chunks of code.

Comment: This code smells, with `If 1` block or without it. A better way is to refactor at a higher level. Make sure you don't have InputParameter1, InputParameter3 and all values are strictly typed, for example `Dim table` -> `Dim table As DataTable`. Then think procedural.

Comment: The OOP answer is to use OOP, create a single-responsibility method.  But the answer you're looking for is... `With Nothing` ... `End With`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `Option Strict On`, that'd have to be `If True Then`, but the more preferred option (as far as I have seen) is `Do ... Loop While False`.

But, no there is no syntax like a simple `Begin ... End` (or `{ ...}`).

If you can work with an `IDisposable`, and have it disposed at the end of the block, `Using newVariable = AnIDisposable` gives you the closest to what you're describing, but like I said, it is disposed at the end.

Comment: Actually, although I haven't seen it used, this is possibly slightly more readable: `Do ... Exit Do : Loop`. (With the `:` I'm just showing where there's a statement break in this comment, not suggesting that should be how it is put in the code.)

Comment: Thank you for finding several options.

Comment: IMHO, `If True Then` is far preferable to a loop that is immediately exited. REASON: Whenever a person reading your code sees a loop construct, they have to mentally double-check to make sure the loop really is only being executed once. REASON #2: a loop has the potential to be misused. If I was debugging unfamiliar code, and saw a strange loop construct (`Loop While False` or `Exit Do : Loop`), that would be a significant distraction.

Answer (score 4):

Re-factor your procedure so there's another procedure in which table and new_row do their thing.  If you really don't need them to be visible later on, then they are doing a distinct sub-task that should be refactored anyway.

Generally speaking, when you can partition your code into N segments, where each segment has no dependency on the others, then you are looking at N tasks and preferably N procedures.

This goes back to the rule that any procedure should do one thing, and multiple segments are a sign that it's doing more than one thing.

Comment: Extreme OO does not always make a short program easier to follow.   See Kevlin Henney's corollary "...except for the problem of too many layers of indirection."

Comment: True, which is why I put "Generally".  Every rule has exceptions, and that's why I provided an explanation. Obviously, I expect the OP to exercise judgment and understand the whys.  But also keep in mind that the OP wanted to separate out the variables anyway, and IMO this kills two birds with one stone.  If it's really that important to separate out variables, then I think it's a modularization issue.

Comment: It is definitely a code smell that it needs refactored.  There are several, short, almost-identical blocks of within a large procedure that reference different sources in slightly different ways.  But I'm asking for knowledge about language features, not refactoring advice.